# Pasar una fecha "01/02/2021" a "01-02-2021" en bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en Bash scripting. Tengo una columna llena de fechas del estilo "01/02/2021" y me gustaría pasar toda la columna a "01-02-2021", solo he encontrado código para cambiar el año, pero nada parecido. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es sólo remplazar barras por guiones? `echo "01/02/2021" | sed "s/\//-/g"`

Answer (score 2):

Aquí un ejemplo para probar en la línea de comandos:

```
$ read -p "  Introducir fecha >> " DATE; printf "  En formato DD-MM-AAAA >> %s\n" "$(date -d"$DATE" +%d-%m-%Y)"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

algo sencillo que se me ocurre es usar sed, si estás guardando esto en un archivo, seria algo asi

```
    sed "s/\//-/g" archivo > nuevo_archivo
```

lo único que esto te reemplaza toda barra que esté en el archivo, esto es aplicable a cualquiera string o carácter, y para los caracteres especiales como es el caso de la barra "/" solo debes agregar una barra invertida "" para salvar el carácter, yo lo uso mucho cuando tengo que cambiar todos las comas decimales(",") por puntos (".")

```
   sed "s/\,/./g" archivo > nuevo_archivo
```